# Scope that filters two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a collection of *Maps* that belong to *Hotels* in my Rails App. I'm looking to filter through all Maps using their *status*. This is working using the following scope:

```
scope :status, -> (status) {where status: status}
```

I'm looking to exclude all **Maps** that belong to **Hotels** with the **status** of X. This is what I have tried, but I'm having no luck with this. I have the following scope inside the **Hotel** model:

```
scope :exclude, -> (status) {where.not(status: status)}
```

and this is what I'm trying inside my **Map** model:

```
scope :status, -> (status) {where(status: status) && Hotel.exclude(1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your relationships, but try:

```
Map.status(map_status).joins(:hotel).merge(Hotel.exclude(hotel_status))
```

In Map:

```
scope :choose_name, ->(map_status, hotel_status) { status(map_status).joins(:hotel).merge(Hotel.exclude(hotel_status)) }
```

Then `Map.choose_name(map_status, hotel_status)`

Comment: Thanks for this, but how would I write this in a Scope?

Comment: edited my answer, I'm not sure of the expected naming though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but I would think that you could do something like:

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :exclude, -> (status) {
    joins(:hotel).where(Hotel.arel_table[:status].not_eq(status))
  }
end
```